# tablesorter widget filter any match. How to only have search all columns (remove search for individual columns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to add a search filter to tablesorter but the only widget i could find adds a search for all columns and a search input for each individual column. I only want the search for all columns active and the functionality of searching in individual columns disabled.

This is the JS `$(function() {

```
var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
        // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
        // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
        // external filter (column specific or any match)
        filter_external : '.search',
        // add a default type search to the first name column
        filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
        // include column filters
        filter_columnFilters: true,
        filter_placeholder: { search : 'Search...' },
        filter_saveFilters : true,
        filter_reset: '.reset'
    }
});
// make demo search buttons work
$('button[data-column]').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        totalColumns = $table[0].config.columns,
        col = $this.data('column'), // zero-based index or "all"
        filter = [];

    // text to add to filter
    filter[ col === 'all' ? totalColumns : col ] = $this.text();
    $table.trigger('search', [ filter ]);
    return false;
});
```

});`

[Here is a link to the table](http://sellingtweets.com/4/)

The search input in each column is what i want removed.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above, column filters are being enabled:

```
// include column filters
filter_columnFilters: true,
```

Set this option to `false` and the filter row will not be created (see [`filter_columnFilter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-columnfilters)).

Comment: Thanks. I'm absolutely amazed i missed that. Guess i was staring at it for too long last night.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I see here is to add a css line to hide the search input in each column.

```css
.input.tablesorter-filter {
    display: none;
}
```